# including bootstrap.min.js breaks dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a `navbar-collapse`.
If I use the code shown below, dropdowns stop working. (Clicking a dropdown item does nothing.)

```
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body { padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way
            to the bottom of the topbar */ }
    </style>
    <!-- Le javascripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='/js/jquery.cookie.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

removing the ref to bootstrap.min.js makes dropdowns work correctly. I'm confused. Am I not supposed to include both .js and .css?

(I tried including jQuery before the css files. Same result.)
(I also tried including javascript before css. Same result.)
All bootstrap files were downloaded straight from the bootstrap website.

Comment: I would recommend downloading from the bootstrap website again and checking the JS console for errors. You need both JS and CSS and typically you put JS after CSS.

Comment: Just tried. No errors on the console.

Comment: Wasn't me. Are you saying the dropdown does not working when the navbar is collapsed?

Comment: No, I'm saying the navbar never works unless `bootstrap.min.js` is not referenced.

Comment: Do they work on the Bootstrap website?

Answer (score -1):

The reference to the bootstrap.js file is important since the drop down function is included in it . On line 637 in bootstrap.js the drop-down definition is defined . like :

```
  var toggle = '[data-toggle=dropdown]'
, Dropdown = function (element) {
    var $el = $(element).on('click.dropdown.data-api', this.toggle)
    $('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', function () {
      $el.parent().removeClass('open')
    })
  }
```

The same way its defined in the bootstrap.min.js which is minified version of bootstrap.js . Removing the reference to the bootstrap.js file will not make the dropdown function to work .

Also I will advise you to use the javascripts in footer .. like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='/js/jquery.cookie.js'></script>
```