# bootstrap.min.js caused dropdown to break

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap control in a webpage to run filters on a table, which works well.

this is the filterable control \ plug in i am using [filterable](https://github.com/lightswitch05/filterable)

I am referencing the js files like so at the footer of my web page and the css at the top of the page in the header

header

```
    <link href="../Static/bootstrap-filterable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.4.5/bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

footer

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.4.5/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the problem with it like the issue this fella is having here [same issue, but no solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037000/including-bootstrap-min-js-breaks-dropdown)

is that i have to reference bootstrap.min.js which in turn breaks my drop down buttons that are referened like this

```
 <div class="btn-group" style="padding-top: 5px">

                <div class="btn-group" id="statusSelctor">
                    <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" style="height: 40px;" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select Status<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding-left: 10px">
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="statuscblist" runat="server">
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

is there something that i am missing with this?

I would be grateful if someone could help get this working as I need both to work.

Thanks

Comment: could you just provide an example with jsbin ? would be much appreciated

Comment: just doing now, sorry, had to leave the office

Comment: the fiddle im using wont allow me to reference the js files and i dont have them locally, however i have noticed that i have two bootstrap.min.js files referened, but if i use the one referenced in the question, my link button doesnt work, if i use the one that was in there originally the filters wont work

Comment: because i cant load the js files into to the jsbin or the fiddle i cant get the drop down to render as it should do

Comment: it is possible to load external resources (over http/https) in jsfiddle. There is a menu point for that. YOu're right JsBin isn't allowing it, but I can do it on jsfiddle.

Comment: can you show me in your fiddle how youve done this, i dont use jsfiddle that much, am new(ish) to web

Comment: Here is a really simple one: "alerting your D3 version number 3.5.3" http://jsfiddle.net/r73x6cyu/ -> on the left menu you see "External Resources" and a "1" klick on it.